# SSRS error must declare scalar variable when using ODBC connection to SQL SERVER

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, dataset, odbc, sql-server-2014

I have an SSRS dataset query with a single value parameter called BENEFIT. My datasource is SQL SERVER 2014: The following query gives the error "ERROR [42000] [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Must declare the scalar variable "@BENEFIT".

```
SELECT  c.BENEFIT  FROM  CLAIM AS c
WHERE c.DOWNLOAD_DATE > '20150701' AND c.BENEFIT = (@ BENEFIT)
```

The error exists ONLY when using an ODBC connection and goes away using a direct connection. Without the parameter the query parses correctly using either connection method.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Thanks,
Alasdair

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ODBC does not support named parameters, so try changing the parameter name to `?`:

`SELECT c.BENEFIT FROM CLAIM AS c WHERE c.DOWNLOAD_DATE > '20150701' AND c.BENEFIT = ?`

Further information here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.90).aspx

Pay mind to the section "Using Parameters with an OleDbCommand or OdbcCommand."

Comment: Hi iDrian - this is an SSRS dataset query. I've updated my text to be more clear!

Comment: @Holdfast4 I understand, but my answer still stands. ODBC connections from ANY source do not support named parameters. Please try what I recommended above.

Comment: Thanks this does work.  I will avoid ODBC.  Interstingly Crystal reports will parse and replace named parameters in a command object(dataset).  It seems SSRS is less developed in this regard.

Answer (score 0):

`SET NOCOUNT ON` before the query and then `SET NOCOUNT OFF` after the query if you declare the variable in the query. If the variable is declared outside the query then use `?` as PicoDeGallo stated.

Comment: Does not work. You cannot get away from the limitations of the ODBC driver. Nothing to do with the code or the query